# access python class variable from method

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and am trying to figure out how to access the global variable count within the repr method in the Student class below:

```
class Student(object):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get("name")
        self.age = kwargs.get("age")
        Student.count += 1
    def __repr__(self):
        try:
            return "name: %s, age: %d" % (self.name, self.age)
        except TypeError:
            print "student number: %d" % (Student.count)
```

When I create an instance, such as student = Student, and the try to print the variable student, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "school.py", line 23, in __repr__
    print "student number: %d" % (Student.count)
NameError: global name 'count' is not defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `self.count` when in the scope of the class and `Student.count` when outside.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Is this the exact traceback, copy/pasted (**not retyped**) from actual interpreter output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access class properties as well using `self`. Not that in your case, your error handling in `__repr__` isn’t necessary. In a method, `self` will always be correct (unless you really mess something up), so you can just assume that you can access `self` properly. As you initialize `name` and `age` in the initializator, you can also assume that both properties exist:

```
class Student (object):
    count = 0
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.age = kwargs['age']
        self.count += 1

    def __repr__ (self):
        return "name: %s, age: %d" % (self.name, self.age)
```

Instead of accepting just `**kwargs`, it might be a good idea to actually ask for `name` and `age` as proper parameter in the initializator. Since you do expect `name` and `age` to be specified, incorrectly calling your constructor will fail early that way:

```
def __init__ (self, name, age, **kwargs): # **kwargs in case you want to accept more
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.count += 1
```

That all being said, the error you show shouldn’t happen. There shouldn’t be an exception being thrown in `__repr__`, and `Student.count` should be accessible as well. So you are probably calling `__repr__` in some weird way. The proper way would be something like this:

```
a = Student(name='Peter', age=15)
print(repr(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.count` instead of `Student.count` inside the class. You do not need to use `Student.count` because you are still inside the class, `self` refers to anything inside the class. It doesn’t need to be inside the `__init__` function. For example:

```
class RandomClass:
    random_var = 0
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
    another_var = 3
    def __str__(self):
        print(“Printing variables: %d and %d” % (self.random_var, self.another_var))#using self.random_var, not RandomClass.random_var
```